# Can you pull unique documents into a email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, automationstudio, campaign

Is there anyway that when you send a email out you can attach a document which is unique to that person?

**As an example, sending 100 people each their own unique document with their personal information on it within an email send. Is this something can be done with SFMC? Or, is a third party needed?**

I'm not too familiar with this in SFMC and if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done using the [`AttachFile`](https://ampscript.guide/attachfile/) function which can attach the personalized file from such locations as:

- HTTP - which basically means you have an external server where you would store the files and just provide the URL of the personalized file
- FTP of Marketing Cloud - you would need a process that uploads personalized files into this FTP provided by Marketing Cloud

Those files would need to have unique IDs that are available  for Marketing Cloud, so that when the email is sent to a given customer, a matching file ID with the personalized file would be known and used by this script.

As such, a 3rd party is necessary to create the personalized files (MC can't do that) and either upload them to MC or make their URLs available for MC.

---

This feature is not free and is not a feature that's available out of the box, so it needs to be requested from the Account Executive alongside an order of attachments (they come in packs of 1000s, with a pack costing a couple dollars).

Each time a file is attached into an email, 1 attachment unit would be consumed. This also means that that if you attach multiple files to a single email, multiple attachment units will be consumed.